# Mock Locations and Production

Tags: android, android-location

I'm using the user's location and testing with mock locations, but I couldn't figure out how should my code look when uploading to production (to Google Play). I mean, now that I'm developing and QA-ing, my code contains mock locations generation and the manifest includes a request for `ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION` permission.

It sound weird to have these permissions requested on production. Am I expected to remove the permissions and the code that deals with mock locations before uploading my app? Besides, while QA-ing I'm using a developer-mode device with mock location settings enabled.

I've read Google's [Testing Using Mock Locations](http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html) guide but despite the following statement, I don't understand how it is actually done: "since you can send the mock data from outside your production app, you don't have to disable or remove test code before you publish.".

Perhaps my misunderstanding is because of the way I coded it, so here it is:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private LocationClient mLocationClient; 

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    }
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }
    protected void onStop() {
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }
    private Location createLocation(double lat, double lng, float accuracy) {
        // Create a new Location
        Location newLocation = new Location("flp");
        newLocation.setLatitude(lat);
        newLocation.setLongitude(lng);
        newLocation.setAccuracy(accuracy);
        return newLocation;
    }
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        //null is my indication to use mocks
        if(currentLocation==null){
            if(isMockSettingsON(getApplicationContext())){
                mLocationClient.setMockMode(true);
                currentLocation = createLocation(LAT, LON, ACCURACY);
                mLocationClient.setMockLocation(currentLocation);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```